# Glassfish Process Killed

Tags: linux, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a strange problem, I am running glassfish 3.1.2.2 on an Amazon AMI Linux Instance and the server runs perfectly fine for about two weeks but than it will just die. There is nothing in the server.log about it, one minute it is serving requests like normal and the next the entire process is gone. I have checked the operating system logs like /var/log/messages. In particular I have looked for the oom-killer because one of my thoughts was the process was being reaped for using to much memory or something, but there is nothing about killing the process in the logs. Does anyone of any ideas for tracking down this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the instance? Some instances aren't guaranteed to be running 24x7

Comment: Yes I am sure, current uptime on my instance is 70 days 14 hours. If the instance was shutdown this would have been reset.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes glassfish needs more memory as our expectations.Please look into JVM tunning as well as assign more memory to glassfish.I am sure that this is due to GC turnover and your server get crashed.I hope you haven't installed it on virtual machine.

Comment: It is installed on an Amazon EC2 virtual machine.

Comment: then increase your virtual space